# while loop iterating only once while reading from inputstream

Tags: java, android, while-loop, inputstream

I am beginner in android and i am working on `InputStream` to read data. I have used while loop for continuously reading data. But while debugging using breakpoints , while loop is running only once. Please help me.

my runnable class is

```
static class Connect implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.43.79", 23);
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            connected = true;
            while(connected) {
                try {
                    p = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "ASCII");
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason why it would exit your loop is because an error is thrown. Try to put a brackpoint in the catch block. Or else, try to catch "Throwable"  instead of IOException and put a breakpoint in the catch block.

Comment: `IOUtils.toString()` reads all bytes until end of the stream in one time.  So you do not need to repeatedly call it.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your code I can guess that an IOException is being thrown by IOUtils.toString(..) and that exception is causing your program to exit the while loop and instead jump to the catch(..) block.

If you can give the output from e.printStackTrace() that would be very helpful. Without it I can't tell you much more.

Comment: @pmartin8 I have checked if any exception is being thrown by any catch block , using breakpoints... and it shows no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`connected` is a non-local variable, so any code where the definition is visible can change it.

If indeed no exception is indeed thrown, then there **must** be some other code changing that variable.

Your code snippet does not even include declarations for the variable (so it won't compile as-is). But I'm guessing that the code changing the variable is rather far away from what you are showing. To identify the problem, I recommend you search for the definition of `connected` and review all its uses.